# How to convert numerical amount in words in indian format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

I have written the below script to convert any CCY to INR based on the latest exchange rate available on the following website and then convert that resulting number to words in indian numbering style. the code works perfectly it just that i am not getting the print in words in proper indian format `Rs 198400` should be `one lakh night eight thousand four hundred rupees only`.

```
import requests
import num2words

def convert_ccy_to_inr(ccy_amount, ccy):
    # Get the latest exchange rate for the specified currency
    r = requests.get(f"https://api.exchangerate-api.com/v4/latest/{ccy}")
    exchange_rate = r.json()["rates"]["INR"]

    # Convert the currency amount to INR using the exchange rate
    inr_amount = ccy_amount * exchange_rate

    # Convert the INR amount to words in the Indian numbering system
    inr_amount_words = num2words.num2words(inr_amount, lang='en_IN')

    return inr_amount_words

# Accept user input for the currency amount and currency code
ccy_amount = float(input("Enter the currency amount: "))
ccy = input("Enter the currency code (e.g. USD, GBP, EUR): ")

# Convert the currency amount to INR and display the result
inr_amount_words = convert_ccy_to_inr(ccy_amount, ccy)
print(f"{ccy_amount} {ccy} is equivalent to {inr_amount_words} rupees")
```

Comment: `night eight thousand`, you mean `ninety eight thousand`?

Comment: yes that's correct

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting the desirable answer because num2words module is returning the words with commas(,) and decimal number. To solve this you can  use these steps:

1. use `inr_rupees, inr_paisa = "{:.2f}".format(inr_amount).split(".")`
   to round up the value upto 2 decimal value and to split it with
   respect to `"."` and assign values to `inr_rupees` and `inr_paisa`
2. Convert the INR Rupees and Paisa amount to words and return as a
   list `[inr_amount_words, inr_paisa_amount_words]`
3. use `convert_ccy_to_inr(ccy_amount, ccy)[0]` to fetch 1st element
   from the word list and use `.replace(",", "")` and
   `.replace("and","")` method to remove unwanted "and" and ",".
4. do same for `inr_paisa_amount_words` (except the "and" part)

so Your final code should be:

```
import requests
import num2words

def convert_ccy_to_inr(ccy_amount, ccy):
    # Get the latest exchange rate for the specified currency
    r = requests.get(f"https://api.exchangerate-api.com/v4/latest/{ccy}")
    exchange_rate = r.json()["rates"]["INR"]

    # Convert the currency amount to INR using the exchange rate
    inr_amount = ccy_amount * exchange_rate
    inr_rupees, inr_paisa = "{:.2f}".format(inr_amount).split(".")
    # Convert the INR amount to words in the Indian numbering system
    inr_amount_words = num2words.num2words(inr_rupees, lang='en_IN')
    inr_paisa_amount_words = num2words.num2words(inr_paisa, lang='en_IN')

    return [inr_amount_words, inr_paisa_amount_words]

# Accept user input for the currency amount and currency code
ccy_amount = float(input("Enter the currency amount: "))
ccy = input("Enter the currency code (e.g. USD, GBP, EUR): ")

# Convert the currency amount to INR and display the result
inr_rupees_amount_words = convert_ccy_to_inr(ccy_amount, ccy)[0].replace(",","").replace("and","")
inr_paisa_amount_words = convert_ccy_to_inr(ccy_amount, ccy)[1].replace(",","")

print(f"{ccy_amount} {ccy} is equivalent to {inr_rupees_amount_words} rupees and {inr_paisa_amount_words} paisa")
```

example output:

> ```
> Enter the currency amount: 6
> Enter the currency code (e.g. USD, GBP, EUR): usd
> 6.0 usd is equivalent to four hundred  ninety-six rupees and thirty-eight paisa
> ```

Comment: actually, there is one more issue with num2words lib, when i am trying to print Rs47.31 i am getting the following 3.0 BRL is equivalent to Rs47.31, (forty-seven point three one), should it be forty-seven rupees and thirty one paise

Comment: ohkay, I have fixed it now

Comment: you can remove  `.replace("and","")` if you want to get an output like this nineteen thousand two hundred **and** seventy-six rupees **and** nine paisa (2 and)

Comment: Try converting 200000000000 EUR to INR using the above code

Comment: seems like will have to use a different library than num2words as it cant handle large integers

Comment: Ohkay I will update my answer as soon as I will find the substitute